# Unable create new pub/sub inputs using a new service account with pub/sub viewer and pub/sub subscriber roles

Tags: service-accounts

I am not able to create new pub/sub inputs using a new service account with pub/sub viewer and pub/sub subscriber roles.  Is there a workaround, outside of binding the permissions at the project level? If we do not want to go with projects level just service accounts without under project can we create pub/sub inputs.

I am trying to using service accounts who does not in any project level permission. Could I achieve  this?